# Why does total energy of N coupled harmonic oscillators increase with increase in N?

Tags: physics, motion, verlet-integration

[image]I am trying to analyse the energy behaviour of n coupled harmonic oscillators where the initial displacements are distributed/defined by  sine wave equation at various values of time. My total energy plot seems to appx. double from n= 4 to 8 to 16 and so on. Can someone please explain me the behaviour.
thanks.

Comment: Maybe better answered here:  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, the more moving stuff, the more energy? That is logical no? Unless we are missing information that you have not given, this makes sense

Comment: thanks, i was still editing. My question is why we do not see this increase in energy when the initial displacement of first particle is 1 and others at rest to start with. In such a case the energy is always constant at 1 for any numbe rof particles from n= 4 onwards

Comment: Questions asking about topics not directly related to software development or programming are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might be able to get help on https://physics.stackexchange.com or https://scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to scicomp.stackexchange.com or physics.stackexchange.com